# How to proceed - 3 scripts & 2 csv files into an executable file for Win & Lin & android & IOS

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sooooo. After building this for months, I finally wrote by first python app. Well, it's not yet an executable app. That's what I'm here for.

The 3 python scripts (one calls the second, which in turn calls the third one) and 2 data files are in the same folder. All ready. What do I do now to build an executable file? I find the single-file-to-executable tutorials good to follow, but the specific setup of 5 files of 2 different types made me wonder how to realize my goal. Can anyone send me into the right direction? And how does the app know the file location when someone installs the app in some random place?

Comment: What did you find by reading the documentation for the packaging apps you looked at?

Comment: you can try https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/

Comment: MattDMo. I simply duckduckgo'ed "create an executable from 2 python script ubuntu / windows ,... and I took it from there. But the things seemed to be one complexity step less than what I need.

Answer (score -1):

```
exec(open('file.py').read())
```

run this to run another file, and so on.

```
runfile('/Users/untitled1.py', wdir='/Users/autosave')
```

that could also help.

If you need to run it, try pushing f5 on your editor.

to build a useable file with these commands in it, create a .py file in your editor.

if your issue is you need an editor, follow these steps to download one.
https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html

the code knows where the file is via a tree.
for example:

/Users/Andrew/.spyder-py3/autosave/untitled1.py

Comment: Thanks. I use Thonny. Spyder hung itself on my ubuntu.